# Coloring exceptions from Python on a terminal

Tags: python, exception, colors

Is there an easy way to get the *message* of the exception to be colored on the command line? For example

```
def g():    f()
def f():    1/0
g()
```

Gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    g()
  File "test.py", line 1, in g
    def g():    f()
  File "test.py", line 2, in f
    def f():    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I would like "**integer division or modulo by zero**" to be colored or highlighted on the terminal so that I can quickly pick it out of a long traceback (Linux only). Ideally, I wouldn't want to write a custom class for each Exception, but somehow catch and format all kinds.

**EDIT:** The question linked in the comments gives examples on how to solve the problem with *external* software, but I'm interested in an internal Python solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is a lot of good information in there and I may use that, but them all seem to involve solutions _outside_ of python, i.e. highlighting the code after it has been run. I'm looking to do something internal (I'll edit the question accordingly).

Comment: You'll have to hook up your own exception handler that then runs the traceback through pygments perhaps instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What you just said, presumably, is what I'm asking. I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: If the terminal you're using supports it, perhaps you could embed [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in exception messages. There's probably a module for that.

Comment: Here's a [table](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) of the ANSI escape sequences -- you many not even need a module to do it.

Comment: Well, in bash you can always print in colours by prepending a string with `'\033[#m'` and appending it with `'\033[0m'` (to go back to no colours). `print('\033[92mGreen!\033[0m')` -- looks like martineau beat me to it.

Comment: @martineau: Pygments does the ANSI part for Python tracebacks. The trick is binding it together.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can assign a custom function to the [`sys.excepthook` handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). The function is called whenever there is a *unhandled* exception (so one that exits the interpreter).

```
def set_highlighted_excepthook():
    import sys, traceback
    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
    from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter

    lexer = get_lexer_by_name("pytb" if sys.version_info.major < 3 else "py3tb")
    formatter = TerminalFormatter()

    def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
        tbtext = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
        sys.stderr.write(highlight(tbtext, lexer, formatter))

    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

set_highlighted_excepthook()
```

This version uses the [`pygments` library](http://pygments.org/) to convert the traceback text into one formatted with ANSI coloring, before writing it to `stderr`.

Someone turned this into a project that detects terminal support and lets you set the pygments style, see [`colored-traceback.py`](https://github.com/staticshock/colored-traceback.py).

Comment: Exactly what parts of the traceback will be highlighted, all of it?

Comment: @martineau: all of it. You'd have to tweak the configuration of the lexer and/or vary what you pass in to make it highlight fewer things.

Comment: To get `pygments`, all I had to do was `$ easy_install Pygments` from any directory.

Comment: This does not colorize syntax errors (indentation error etc.). Is there a way to color even these?

Comment: @frederick99 Syntax errors are tracebacks too, but if the error is in the file that would set the hook or import the module that sets the hook then there is no hook to intercept the traceback. A syntax error exception is thrown at the point where the file with the error is imported (as that triggers compilation).

Comment: @frederick99 you can add the hook to your [`sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) to have it run before Python tried to run the main script, that way it is guaranteed to be installed before syntax errors can be found.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i can confirm pythonrc does not have syntax errors and the hook is set. https://imgur.com/WqDhsxX

Comment: @frederick99: thanks for the report, I figured out what is going wrong and removed the `stripall` argument, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hi0o.png for the new output.

Answer (score 6):

Found another way to do this using the IPython module which is likely a dependency that everyone already has installed:

```
from IPython.core.ultratb import ColorTB
c = ColorTB()
exc = sys.exc_info()
print(''.join(c.structured_traceback(*exc)))
```

Comment: Should use `ColorTB().text(*exc)` instead of joining the string manually because if ColorTB is set to other modes other than 'plain', manually joining will not work.

Answer (score 4):

This takes the solution @freakish shared and makes the colorization part of the exception instead of requiring the user to add color to each exception message. Obviously, it only works for custom exceptions, so it may not be exactly what OP was looking for.

```py
from colorama import Fore, init
init()

class Error (Exception):
    def __init__ (self, message):
        super().__init__(Fore.RED + message)

class BadConfigFile (Error):
    pass

raise BadConfigFile("some error message")
```

This will print the traceback with "some error message" in red.  Having 'Error' as a base class means you can create other exceptions that will all inherit the colorization of the message.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) ( or any other coloring ) module. Then you can wrap you're entire app with:

```
import traceback
from colorama import Fore, init
init( )

try:
    // your app
except Exception:
    print Fore.RED + traceback.format_exc( ) + Fore.RESET
    // possibly raise again or log to db
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. Would it be possible to do with without having "my app" be indented in a try block?

Comment: @Hooked I don't think so. But is this a problem? Put your entire app inside a function and then call the function and the wrap the function with `try:except` block. Also it might be more complex if threads are involved.

Comment: You could probably avoid the `try:except` block around your whole app by using `sys.excepthook` as described in Martijn Pieters' answer.