# Is there a way to have a python program run an action when it's about to crash?

Tags: python

I have a python script with a loop that crashes every so often with various exceptions, and needs to be restarted. Is there a way to run an action when this happens, so that I can be notified?

Comment: Related: [Coloring exceptions from Python on a terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14775916)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could install an exception hook, by assigning a custom function to the [`sys.excepthook` handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). The function is called whenever there is a *unhandled* exception (so one that exits the interpreter).

```
import sys

def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
    import traceback
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    tbtext = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
    msg = MIMEText("There was a problem with your program:\n\n" + tbtext)
    msg["From"] = "me@example.com"
    msg["To"] = "you@example.com"
    msg["Subject"] = "Program exited with a traceback."
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())

sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
```

This exception hook emails you the traceback whenever the program exits, provided you have a working `sendmail` command on your system.

Comment: There's little hack responses from low rep (including me, beh.) and THE response from the great Python master, a.k.a. Martijn. Well done.

Comment: Besides that, Martijn's response was the most elegant I have to say. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can surrond your whole program with a `try/except` block, which is not very beautiful I find. Another way is to run your python script in a `.sh` file and execute this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    python your_script.py
    if $? != 0 then
        sendmail "blabla" "see the doc" "for arguments"
    fi
done
```

This will execute the Python script and when it stops, it'll send you a mail and restarted it (since it's an infinite loop). The mail is sent only if there's an error in the Python program and the exit code is different of 0. To be more efficient, you could get the stdout, and put it in the mail to know what fails and how resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
while True:
        try:
            x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```