# How to change error text color in vs code terminal for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors, vscode-extensions, highlight

I would like to change the color of text in error to red and/or multiple color for different parts of showing error.

My Vs Code Terminal currently look this this,
[image: Example]

I would like something like this made using rich module, [image] Something like this of pycharm.
[image], or, preferably, like Spyder's looj [image: Spyder]

Adding this "terminal.ansiRed":"#d84240"  is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coloring exceptions from Python on a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775916/coloring-exceptions-from-python-on-a-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

Both PyCharm and Spyder are using `ipython` interpreter when possible (the `ipython` module is installed).
So the most simple solution for interactive shell is to make sure it is installed in your `venv` and invoke `ipython` instead of regular `python` interpreter.

As you can see in my screenshot VsCode is running a regular shell. Python interpreter does not create any colors, but IPython handles colors by itself.
[image]

As for coloring errors/exceptions from within your scripts, you need to handle it programmatically. The easiest way is to install the [pretty_errors](https://github.com/onelivesleft/PrettyErrors/) module, and then you will want to have errors in your code just because they will be so beautiful ;) :
[image]

Comment: I like this pretty_errors module module. Thanks. That is an interesting answer. I would like if it also highlighted my RuntimeWarnings, but I'm testing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Python can convert RuntimeWarnings to exceptions with `warnings.simplefilter("error")`

Answer (score 1):

You can set any colour as you wish in the python code (ANSI escape sequences).

```py
def print_error(message):
    print("\033[33m{}\033[0m".format(message)) # \033[33m sets the color to yellow

try:
    result = 10 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print_error("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
```

```
refer the table for colour code:
Text Color  Foreground Code
Black          \033[30m
Red            \033[31m
Green          \033[32m
Yellow         \033[33m
Blue           \033[34m
Magenta        \033[35m
Cyan           \033[36m
White          \033[37m
Bright Black   \033[90m
Bright Red     \033[91m
Bright Green   \033[92m
Bright Yellow  \033[93m
Bright Blue    \033[94m
Bright Magenta \033[95m
Bright Cyan    \033[96m
Bright White   \033[97m
```

Answer (score 1):

So, coloring things in the terminal from Python has been answered a lot of times so I assume you want to make VSCode use colors for Python exceptions *without* adding more packages and *with* minimal changes to your code. (For completeness I have added an excellent method to color the traceback like your Spyder example if you are allowed to add the Pygments package below.)

### Colored Python Exceptions in VSCode Windows Terminal using ANSI codes

The VSCode Windows Terminal supports the ANSI control codes quite well, so adding one before and after the printing of the Python traceback in Python's exit handler will color (and possibly format) the output.

Colors tested with `foo.py`:

```py
print('\033[31mTest\033[0m')
```

You can then create a custom exit handler (see [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)) to add the colors and reset them afterwards at the beginning of your Python program:

```py
def set_highlighted_excepthook():
    import sys, traceback

    def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
        tbtext = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
        sys.stderr.write('\033[31m' + tbtext + '\033[0m')

    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

set_highlighted_excepthook()
```

For more codes to set colors and italics etc. refer to the [ANSI codes: SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). E.g. to set bold/bright red use code **1** followed by **31**: `\033[1;31m`. You can have as many codes as you like as long as you start with `\033[`, separate each code with `;` and end with `m`. Always remember to print `\033[0m` to reset everything back to normal at the end!

### Better Colored Python Exceptions in VSCode Windows Terminal using Pygments:

Install the amazing Pygments package which has a language lexer for Python Tracebacks:

`pip.exe install pygments`

Then set a new excepthook to print through Pygments Python Traceback Lexer and apply your chosen style:

```py
def set_highlighted_excepthook():
    import sys, traceback
    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import PythonTracebackLexer
    from pygments.formatters import Terminal256Formatter

    formatter = Terminal256Formatter(style='xcode')

    def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
        tbtext = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
        sys.stderr.write(highlight(tbtext, PythonTracebackLexer(), formatter))

    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook


set_highlighted_excepthook()
```

Credit: Martijn Pieters https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776693/13269963 updated for 256 Color support.

To change the style change the string `style='xcode'` to one of [Pygments' styles](https://pygments.org/styles/) or create your own!

Comment: That’s neat. Do you happen to know where I can find instructions demonstrating how I can run this code in the terminal when ever I invoke Python in VS code? It’s a tidbit cumbersome to remember to run this code whenever I run something.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know of a way to get vscode to inject it into your project. The closest I could come was to edit your project very lightly. Alternatively, you could create a `dev.py` file which adds the code above, and then imports and invokes your real project passing on `argc`, `argv` etc. - that way you can get the colors without touching your original project code?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do exactly what the screenshot of the OP shows, namely install rich's traceback handler, for the whole virtual environment.

1. Execute `python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])'` ([source](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/106#issuecomment-778033925))
2. Create the directory `sitecustomize` within the directory obtained in 1.
3. Within this directory create the file `__init__.py` with the contents

```py
from rich.traceback import install
install()
```

Then in VS Code execute the command "Python: Select Interpreter" and select the Python interpreter from the venv.

From now on when executing a file in the embedded terminal or a region in the Python interpreter tracebacks will be colorful.

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at the diff. options: [color options](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/).

In vs-code you can edit them by accessing the settings.json file. (On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings or Shortcut(ctrl,)).

There you have the ability to change your colorization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question's focus is how to modify the text color to red specifically for error messages. Could you kindly provide more detailed instructions?

Comment: @EricFail so are you looking for something that you can add to your code that will change the color based on what is being printed to the terminal or are you wanting something that "knows" what color an error message to be?  The former is doable, but the latter is more much harder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34691566)